# how to change data such that graph is interrupted

Tags: matlab, graph

I'd like to construct a graph like the following which is done with excel:
[image]

I've entered my data into matlab using the following lines:

**year = [1975  1976    1977    1978    1979    1980    1981    1982    1983    1984    1985    1986         1987   1988    1989    1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995    1996    1997    1998    1999    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
]**

**fix_No = [-9.449167466    -11.19432509    -8.500517848    -5.644813211    -2.608063866    2.614370892 6.461752833 7.035549084 8.542521755 12.11070577     6.476900841 8.029225388 4.315820526 4.165349512 5.34593031  7.510812752 -2.629044124    -5.713139529    -8.626773532    -11.83226415    .   -8.821345246    -6.396197293    -5.187823611    -1.79008821 3.34099288  5.545228048 7.013763711 6.580524638 4.256524275
]**

**fix_No_and_mean = [11.1610424 5.437315474 5.833032482 4.591658232 1.578021362 -1.572756298    -1.03351595 -2.250991302    -3.222969261    -5.734621837    .   12.96685642 10.95095066 10.2207684  5.654017602 1.753259697 -2.596143576    -7.155087995    -9.687001589    -8.700979283    -4.290434459    .   2.299711172 1.640802028 1.714407543 0.8360893   -0.425484303    -1.160053823    -0.858530711    0.123787867 0.782208621
]**

In 1985 and 1996 the lines should be interrupted as in the excel graph. But how can I do this using Matlab? I've put a "." (point) where the interruptions should be but matlab doesn't accept points. 
The lines for the construction of the graph look like this:

```
plot(year,fix_No, 'color', 'k', 'LineWidth',2, 'LineSmoothing','on')
line(year,fix_No_and_mean, 'color', 'r', 'LineWidth',2, 'LineSmoothing','on')
xlabel('year')
legend('fixed number', 'fixed number')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Should put "NaN" instead of '.' ,i.e. in the places on the vectors `fix_No_and_mean` and `fix_No` that correspond to 1985 and 1996, put `NaN`.

This will plot different lines as in the figure you attached from excel.